# Linking to a Css Stylesheet doesnt implement font-family

Tags: font-face

I have a masterpage, I want to use `@font-face` property to my font from the  stylesheet. I have a font called `Vera-Bold.ttf` inside `fonts/Vera-Bold.ttf`.  I used `font-face` property i.e,

```
@font-face {
font-family:'myFirstFont';
src: url('Bootstrap/dist/fonts/Vera-Bold.ttf') ;}
```

inside `style.css`, which I've linked to my masterpage as

```
<link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but the fonts didnt change. How is this not working? I will be thankful if any one helps me on this.

Comment: Go to developer (in firefox) or developer tools ( in chrome ), and then console, see if there is any error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following instructions, you'll get your answer.

1. Define your font face in a CSS file (like skin.css) as follow:

`@font-face {
    font-family: Vera-Bold;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('Bootstrap/dist/fonts/Vera-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
 }`

be careful about your relative address. This address is relative from the location of your font file to `skin.css`

2. Link your CSS file in your `<head>` section.

   e.g.: `<link href="skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
3. Use your font.

Comment: thanks but still it's not working. It used to work but when i started using masterpage and linked it to the css file, all other css effects are working except the font-family.I've used the same way to declare the font-face property as u've shown.

Comment: Dear @SanzayShakyaR , I Tested the font-face myself. Downloded the font from [link](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bitstream-vera-sans). It worked perfectly. Maybe you are addressing the `ttf` file not correctly. Agian, you should address your `ttf` file relative to your `css` file, not your masterpage. Make me aware of your try.

Comment: Well it worked. i replaced the url with,                                                      src: url('/Bootstrap/dist/fonts/Vera-Bold.ttf');.I  put / at the beginning of the path to make the path relative to the document and it worked :) Thanks for your concern and help dear @Soheil Farahani

Comment: I'm glad that you make it. YW.